# Parsing time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

How do you parse time only in C#? For example if the user enters "12:45pm" in a text box? And how would I store the variable, as DateTime or TimeSpan?

This is my code:

```
  public partial class CreateMeetingWindow : Window {
        public string MeetingTYpe { get; set; }
        public string MeetingCode {get; set;}
        public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan MeetingTime { get; set; }
        public bool Cancelled {get; set;}

        public CreateMeetingWindow(Window parent) {
                       InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            MeetingCode = cbxMeetingType.SelectedValue.ToString ();
            MeetingCode = txtMeetingCode.Text;
            MeetingDate = DateTime.Parse(datePicker.SelectedDate.ToString ());
            Cancelled = false;
            this.Hide ();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Cancelled = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

So what I'm concerned about is the variable MeetingTime for example if the user enters it as "12:45pm" in the textbox

Comment: `MeetingDate` should also include the time component, from the looks of it, `MeetingTime` is the *length* of the meeting, not when it begins at. Thats what the data types point to anyway. There isn't a built-in way to store just a time component, just as there isn't a built-in way to store just a date component. `DateTime` stores them both.

Comment: The extended WPF toolkit has a DateTimePicker control that includes both date and time -- it might be of interest to you: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

.NET currently doesn't have a built-in type for time-of-day data.  Your choices are:

- Use a `TimeSpan`, though this is primarily designed for *elapsed-time* values, so it does not support AM/PM designators.
- Use a `DateTime`, with an arbitrary date - being careful not to use the date part anywhere.
- Use the `LocalTime` type from [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), a third-party library.  A `LocalTime` is a true time-of-day type.

Also, I'm not sure why you have:

```
MeetingDate = DateTime.Parse(datePicker.SelectedDate.ToString());
```

Instead of just:

```
MeetingDate = datePicker.SelectedDate;
```

If you want to combine them both, consider:

```
DateTime meetingDate = datePicker.SelectedDate;
DateTime meetingTime = DateTime.Parse(txtMeetingTime);
DateTime meetingDateTime = meetingDate.Date + meetingTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `MeetingTime` is a `TimeSpan` (*which is the right type in your case*), you can't parse a string that contains ante meridiem or post meridiem designators to `TimeSpan`.

These designators are for `DateTime` type. `TimeSpan` is a *time invertal*. I would be meaningless when you try say something like; *12 hours and 45 minutes time invertal after noon*. Doesn't make sense, right?

```
var s = "12:45";
var MeetingTime = TimeSpan.Parse(s);
```

Either you should prevent to typing designators in your textbox forcing entering to format as `hh:mm` or you should use some dropdownlists for entering hours, minutes and second values and combine them in the code behind.